# Weird sentence with zu

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

I have encountered this sentence:

> Ich habe vorsichtig **zu ergründen** gesucht, wie er wirklich ist.

I understand the general meaning but what is "zu ergründen" doing? I need to understand how this sentence got built so I can do the same or something similar in the future. Please explain the structure of this sentence to me. Literal translation to English would help.

Comment: It's an _infinitive_ as with many verbs and _zu_.

Comment: That is absolutely congruent with the English "I tried **to find out**..."

Comment: Even more parallel: *sought to fathom*.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other uses of *zu* with an infinitive, the *zu + inifinitive* construction can also appear with another verb, which is occasionally referred to as the *semi-auxilliary verb*. The main role of the semi-auxilliary verb is to change the meaning of the infinitive in some way, much as the [modal auxilliary verbs](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/readinggerman/category/10-modal/) do. When used in this way, the semi-auxilliary verb encloses the infinitive.

Example:

> Sie hat uns *zu verstehen gegeben*, daß sie morgen kommt.

The book, *Hammer's German Grammar and Usage* by Martin Durrell (ISBN 0-8442-2208-9) has an extended discussion of the various different forms of the *zu + infinitive* construction, including the kind of infinitive clause that you provide. The example above is taken from Durrell.